# Mint Linux Visual Studio terminal cant run commands

Tags: linux, visual-studio

This issue is just driving me crazy. I have used VB with SSH before and had no issues. For the first time I decided to make the change to mint for my computer just run into a crazy amount of privilege's issues. However this one I just cant figure it out.

I am opened the terminal in Visual Studio and tried to send a sudo, php, apt-get literally any command. It will always come back with command not found. I also tried to open a bash terminal and got the same result.

However if I just open a normal mint terminal all the commands work. So it is not that i dont have sudo or apt-get install.

What am i doing wrong here?

[image]

Answer (score -1):

i once had this problem and fixed it by changing the sh ( top right corner of the terminal ) to bash by clicking it, check if maybe you have the option to

Comment: The post says: *"I also tried to open a bash terminal and got the same result*"